# How generate pseudo-random numbers in uniform and gaussian distribution without float/double numbers?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, assembly

I have to write pseudo-random generator on assembler without any float/double operations and functions, like sin/cos, sqrt e.t.c. So I can't use general methods to do that. Also I have limit for random-numbers: 00-0F. How can I do this?

As I understood, I need to generate uniform-number at first. I did it like this: `x = (13 * x + 7) % 16;` (but it has a problem - it's the unifromest distribution ever. If it generated 15 numbers and I know all of them, I can say 16th with 100% probability, because where is no repetition in period which is 16 (module) ).

And after that, I need to regenerate those numbers to gaussian. I found this solution in the internet, but it doesn't work.

```
for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) // N - amount of randomized numbers
{
    ++gx[x = (a * x + c) % m]; //gx - histogram of x
    xm[i] = x; // xm - massive of randomized numbers in uniform
    y = 0;      
    for (j = 0; j < i + 1; ++j)
    {
        y += xm[j] * n - j; // n - primitive number. I choose 13
    }
    y = y / (i + 1);
    y %= m;
    ym[i] = y; // ym - massive of randomized numbers in gaussian
    ++gy[y]; //gy - histogram of y
}
```

What should I do with it?
(I know nothing about probability theory)

I get this output of gx and gy:

```
Uniform
0       4       ****
1       4       ****
2       4       ****
3       4       ****
4       4       ****
5       4       ****
6       4       ****
7       4       ****
8       4       ****
9       4       ****
10      4       ****
11      4       ****
12      4       ****
13      4       ****
14      4       ****
15      4       ****


Normal
0       2       **
1       3       ***
2       8       ********
3       4       ****
4       10      **********
5       4       ****
6       1       *
7       2       **
8       1       *
9       3       ***
10      8       ********
11      4       ****
12      5       *****
13      6       ******
14      1       *
15      2       **
```

Comment: "[...] without float/double numbers?" - by using integers, in first place?

Comment: yes, only integer numbers are allowed

Comment: you will definitely need some probability theory...google box-Muller transformations this should be what you need.

Comment: you can use much larger primes than 7 and 13 and use just 4 bits of the result, see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator

Comment: @tesseract, it uses ln, sin and cos, as I can understand. So it can't help me.

Comment: @Wimmel, I have only 8-bit registers in my property, therefore I chose that numbers. I tried to set a = 43 and c = 117, but there was a non uniform destribution, so I kept it 13 and 7.

Comment: You could look at, say, [`<random>`](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/random) or boost.random for the implementation of distributions. As for the PRNG, the Mersenne Twister is probably a bit complex for asm, but the [WELL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well_Equidistributed_Long-period_Linear)  PRNGs might be a better choice. It also depends on how high the quality of the (statistical) randomness needs to be.

Comment: Split your problem into 1) algorithm for pseudo random number generator, and 2) big integer computing in assembly. You might not need big integer if you are fine with lower quality generators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that a "Gaussian" distribution over the integers in [0, 15] means the [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) B(15, 1/2), the obvious approach is to generate two random bytes, mask the second by `0x7f`, and count the number of bits set. The three-bit version looks like this.

```
0 *
1 *******
2 *********************
3 ***********************************
4 ***********************************
5 *********************
6 *******
7 *
```

If this assumption is incorrect, then please edit your question to specify the exact probability desired for each integer in [0, 15].

If your target platform has an 8-bit multiply with 16-bit output, then it should be possible to get an efficient [Complementary-multiply-with-carry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply-with-carry#Complementary-multiply-with-carry_generators) generator, for example, b = 256 and r = 256 and a = 207, or b = 256 and r = 32 and a = 211. (I'm not sure how much space you have for the generator state or if these parameter choices pass randomness tests.)

Comment: Thanks, bits summarize works well (but I didn't understand how)

Comment: @Nexen It's summing 15 [Bernoulli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) samples, to which distribution the [Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) applies.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [linear feedback shift register](http://www.maximintegrated.com/app-notes/index.mvp/id/4400). All integer calculations, and you can peel off individual bytes to return your random number.

That page is just a particularly easy to approach example. There is lots of stuff available that talks about using LFSRs for generating pseudorandom numbers.

Comment: It was very interesting, but there is no information about it's disctribution. I guess, uniform at best, but I need gaussian still.

Comment: Nexen: The distribution of the LFSR random numbers is going to depend a lot on the polynomial you use. You will have to do some research to discover which one you want.